# SQL query to check if user assigned with a specific value and does not a different value assigned to the same user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, where-clause

We can have users with multiple `valueID`s.  In SQL Server I am trying to pull all users that have `valueID` of `3` but do not have `valueID` of `1` and `2`.  So Table `A` would have a `user` column and a `valueID` column.

How do I write a SQL query to do this?

Also, any good resources to get my SQL query skills up to par?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear you want users with a value of 3 who do not have a value of 1 AND 2 i.e a user with values of 3 and 1 would appear in your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT  user
FROM    A outer
WHERE   valueID = 3
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    A inner
    WHERE
    (
                valueID = 1
        OR      valueID = 2
    )
    AND     inner.user = outer.user
)
```

Comment: @Wolverine313, not according to your question it isn't. This will not find Users with values of 3 and 1 or 3 and 2

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, I only wanted to find users with the value of 3 and they do not also have the value of 1 and 2.  These are the only values ids that exist.  So with this query it does list all users that have a valueID of 3, and they don't also have a valueID of 1 or 2.  My apologies if my original question was not clear.  Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `NOT(1) AND NOT(2) == NOT(1 OR 2)`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Not ( 1 AND 2) != Not (1 Or 2). Still you seem to have got it right by accident..

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I don't know if I would call it an accident, or we two understanding the problem differently, as written.

Comment: Yep, could be worse one clown marked me down for giving the right answer to the question they asked.... I read it as 3 AND !(1 AND 2)

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all users that have values (3 and 1) or (3 and 2) or just 3

```
select user
from mytable t1
where valueId = 3
and (select count(distinct valueId)
from mytable t2 where t2.user = t1.user
and valueId IN (1,2)) < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more.... (all users with valueid = 3 and nothing else)

```
SELECT  [USER]
FROM    A
GROUP BY [USER]
HAVING  MAX(CASE WHEN valueid = 3 THEN 0 when valueid IN (1,2) THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Comment: @Tony True... But I liked the simplicity of it :)  Maybe there is a way to factor that in while retaining the same simplicity?

Comment: @Tony... Edited.  What do you think?

Comment: When valueid in (1,2) Then 1 Else 0, I think. I'd have done it with two joins, though it would appear the OP asked the wrong question anyway...

Comment: Agree with that last part...  in the question, "but do not have valueID of 1 and 2" sounds like "3 and not (1 and 2)"...

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get what you asked if you meant users with a value of 3 except those which also have values of 1 and 2

```
Select s.UserID From SomeTable s
Where s.UserID NOT In 
(select s1s.UserID From SomeTable s1s 
inner join  SomeTable s2s On s1s.UserID = s2s.UserID 
Where s1s.ValueId = 1 And s2s.ValueId = 2)
```

Or

```
Select s.UserID From SomeTable s
Left Join
(select s1s.UserID From SomeTable s1s 
inner join  SomeTable s2s On s1s.UserID = s2s.UserID 
Where s1s.ValueId = 1 And s2s.ValueId = 2) both
Where both.userID is null
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what your table structure is, but it's likely the below query should work depending on column names...

```
SELECT user, valueID
FROM users
WHERE valueID = 3
```

Comment: This will not filter out `user`s that have `valueID` of 1 or 2.